What does "it refer to?

In this context, where survival is clearly not in danger, the desire for pain is actually the desire for a reward, not suffering or punishment. This reward-like effect comes from the feeling of mastery over the pain. The closer you look at your chilli-eating habit, the more remarkable it seems. When the active ingredient of chillies—capsaicin—touches the tongue, it stimulates exactly the same receptor that is activated when any of these tissues are burned. Knowing that our body is firing off danger signals, but that we are actually completely safe, produces pleasure.

This text talks about humans seeking activities that cause a degree of pain in order to experience pleasure. What does "it" refer to? Is it "your chilli-eating habit" or the previous sentence "this reward-like effect comes from the feeling of mastery over the pain"?

There are many contexts where it's impossible to say exactly what it refers to, but in your specific context it's pretty obvious that it = your chili-eating habit (such as once or twice in this very sentence! :). Not that it would make the slightest difference to the meaning of the entire cited text if it actually referred back to any amount of preceding text up to and including the very first sentence starting with In this context... I think semanticl analysis  at this level is worse than useless - it's actually counterproductive.

Here "it" refers to "your chile-eating habit". Grammatically, "it" could refer to anything preceding in the text. But here it only makes sense if it refers to chile eating. The writer's point is that eating chile wouldn't make sense, UNLESS you apply the reasoning of this paragraph. It wouldn't make sense in context to say that "mastery over pain" is amazing. The writer states that mastery over pain is a natural and readily comprehensible desire. He then uses this theory or principle to explain why people like to eat spicy food, which he thinks would otherwise be "amazing".
